# sqlite get EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN result with php

Tags: php, sqlite

How must I execute `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` command to sqlite to get results and show them on the screen with `php` ?
I use simple `Sqlite3` php class https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3.php , but  `query()` return `SQLite3Result` object, not the raw dump.

```
 $result = $db->query("EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * from events WHERE type='comment' AND TIMESTAMP > $time AND PAGE = '$page' LIMIT 1");
 echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) behaves like a query that outputs a four-column table:

```sql
sqlite> .mode columns
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
selectid    order       from        detail                      
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------------------------
2           0           0           USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
0           0           0           COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 1 AND 2
```

You have to output it like a query, i.e., loop over the rows, and print the value in each column.

You might want to use the `sqlite3` command-line shell instead.